# How to summarize/condense down unknown columns while keeping column names

Tags: r

I have a database that I add to, occationally programatically adding new variables as they are detected in the process of research.

Example database and code to add new columns:

...

```
Analysis = data.frame(Experiment = character(),
                      Variable = character(),
                      Test_1_name = character(),
                      Test_1_stat = numeric(),
                      Test_1_p_value = numeric(),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Make Analysis column

if (!variable_name %in% names(Analysis) ) { 

  Analysis = Analysis %>% add_column(tempname = NA)      # adds a new column

  names(Analysis)[names(Analysis) == "tempname"] = variable_name     # renames that column

  Analysis <<- Analysis

}
```

...

In each round of the pipeline a single experiment is performed and a new row is made with the output of that experiment, which will be only two or three entries. This will be done for several different variables (EDIT FOR CLARITY: different entires in the 'variables' column, not columns in the database) and each will have their own row:

...

```
Analysis = Analysis %>% add_row(Experiment = experiment_name, 
                              Variable = var_name,
                              shapiro_stat = test,
                              shapiro_p.value = test)
```

...

These columns are mostly filled with NA. Some columns are character, some numeric, some bool.I want to condense all the rows for a particular experiment down so that I have rows for each group in the 'variables' column in each experiment, essentially collapsing the 'variable' group rows together. If I have three experiements with three variables, I want to end up with nine rows with all the entries for a variable in a single row.

Some example of input data might be:

```
"KGHGKGKGKGKGGHHHHGH" character string
0.23423 float
```

and the output into the column (which I can't predict ahead of time):

```
"class: Halver"
"class: Pelt"
"1.234564332"
"TRUE"
```

The reason for this tables existence is a summary table of the main trunk of a prospecting algorithm. Unfortunately, the very purpose of this is to unify many different data points into a cohesive report.

I have tried groupBy and summerize and I cant get the behaviour I want, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and your expected output based on that data?

Comment: Added to the question body, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up with this:

```
  # Group by experiment and variable and then output separate lists
  
  exp_var_rows = with(Analysis, split(Analysis, paste(Experiment, Variable, sep = "_")))
  
  # Remove the out list's names
  
  exp_var_rows = unname(exp_var_rows, force = FALSE)
  
  # Condense the lists to get the first non-NA value, outputting the rows.
  
  exp_var_rows = lapply(exp_var_rows, function(exp_var_rows){sapply(exp_var_rows, FUN = First_Value)})
  
  # Remove the blank values
  
  exp_var_rows = lapply(exp_var_rows, Remove_Zero_Length_Cells)
  
  # Bind to the Record

  exp_var_rows = dplyr::bind_rows(Record, exp_var_rows)
```